# SparkSQL Timestamp query failure

Tags: scala, timestamp, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I put some log files into sql tables through Spark and my schema looks like this:

```
|-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true) 
|-- c_ip: string (nullable = true) 
|-- cs_username: string (nullable = true) 
|-- s_ip: string (nullable = true) 
|-- s_port: string (nullable = true) 
|-- cs_method: string (nullable = true) 
|-- cs_uri_stem: string (nullable = true) 
|-- cs_query: string (nullable = true) 
|-- sc_status: integer (nullable = false) 
|-- sc_bytes: integer (nullable = false) 
|-- cs_bytes: integer (nullable = false) 
|-- time_taken: integer (nullable = false) 
|-- User_Agent: string (nullable = true) 
|-- Referrer: string (nullable = true)
```

As you can notice I created a timestamp field which I read is supported by Spark (Date wouldn't work as far as I understood). I would love to use for queries like "where timestamp>(2012-10-08 16:10:36.0)" but when I run it I keep getting errors. 
I tried these 2 following sintax forms: 
For the second one I parse a string so Im sure Im actually pass it in a timestamp format. 
I use 2 functions: *parse* and  *date2timestamp*.

Any hint on how I should handle timestamp values?

Thanks!

1) 
    scala> **sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM Logs as l where l.timestamp=(2012-10-08 16:10:36.0)").collect**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.55] failure: ``)'' expected but 16 found 

SELECT * FROM Logs as l where l.timestamp=(2012-10-08 16:10:36.0) 
                                                  ^
```

2) 
    **sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM Logs as l where l.timestamp="+date2timestamp(formatTime3.parse("2012-10-08 16:10:36.0"))).collect**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.54] failure: ``UNION'' expected but 16 found 

SELECT * FROM Logs as l where l.timestamp=2012-10-08 16:10:36.0 
                                                 ^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured that the problem was the precision of the timestamp first of all and also the string that I pass representing the timestamp has to be casted as a **String**

So this query works now:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM Logs as l where cast(l.timestampLog as String) <= '2012-10-08 16:10:36'")
```

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the quotation marks.

Try something with this syntax:

```
L.timestamp = '2012-07-16 00:00:00'
```

Alternatively, try

```
L.timestamp = CAST('2012-07-16 00:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: I had already tried putting single quotes around the timestamp and it looks like it doesn't read it as a timestamp since the result set is empty and it shouldn't.

I also tried the CAST AS suggestion but it doesn't work either. I specifically get this error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.76] failure: ``STRING'' expected but identifier TIMESTAMP found

Comment: Worth noting, for future readers as this is very old.  Timestamp data has millisecond (or better) precision. Just because the display is in second precision doesn't mean the backing data is - it's effectively rounded. When using the equality operator you have to match exactly. With real-world data this is, well, hard.  

Use a bounded time expression, such as "between" to scan a range of times.

Answer (score 2):

Cast the string representation of the timestamp to timestamp.  cast('2012-10-10 12:00:00' as timestamp) Then you can do comparison as timestamps, not strings. Instead of:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM Logs as l where cast(l.timestamp as String) <= '2012-10-08 16:10:36'")
```

try

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM Logs as l where l.timestamp <= cast('2012-10-08 16:10:36' as timestamp)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this didn't work for me. I am using Apache Spark 1.4.1. The following code is my solution:

```
Date date = new Date();

String query = "SELECT * FROM Logs as l where l.timestampLog <= CAST('" + new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()) + "' as TIMESTAMP)";

sqlContext.sql(query);
```

Casting the timestampLog as string did not throw any errors but returned no data.